# Make screen turn blank (no standby) when closing laptop lid

Tags: server, 13.10, xubuntu, laptop

I'm trying to make the screen go off when I close the laptop lid, but the laptop should remain on (no standby). I have Ubuntu server 13.10 , with the `xubuntu-desktop` package installed for convenience (but not meant to run all the time). Currently it does nothing (with or without gui), although the `xfce4-power-manager` marks that it would lock the screen.(Does the gui needs to be on for the settings in the power manager to have effect?). There is also no option in the power manager to only turn the screen off. The switch in the laptop screen does work because it is able to get the system out of standby when I manually suspend it.

(Some additional info:
I'm aware of `logind.conf` of `systemd`: everything is commented there, and if I understood correctly the `HandleLidSwitch=` option does not offer a way to get the screen only blank. The graphics card is an integrated Intel one: `82852/855GM`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate setting in your power manager. If you're using Xfce, then in `xfce4-power-manager` you can access `Preferences`, then you can set in the `Monitor` tab the timeouts for `Put display to sleep` or `Switch off display`. Thus the power manager will turn the screen off after a given timeout period. You need to set this setting in both the `On AC` and `On Battery` tabs.

[image]

It doesn't look like you can easily trigger this behavior `When laptop lid is closed` in `Actions` tab.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to suspend the entire laptop, only to turn off the screen (as stated in the title, but I clarified this in the text). I also forgot to mention that the power manager does not show the option to only turn the screen off.

Comment: Well, you can turn the screen off after a given timeout period that you can set in the `Monitor` tab. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes in fact , of course that works, but I completely missed it because I was so concentrated a finding a way to immediately turn of the screen, lol. I have just seen somewhere the option to do this immediately, but what you suggest is a perfect workaround if is set the timeout period a bit shorter. Still it ignores the 'lock on closing lid' but I don't bother to much about that, laptop won't travel anymore. Thank you! (what do I have to mark as answer now? because it's in a comment now, or do I put this workaround in my question?)

Comment: So the solution is just don't bring the laptop with you if you use Ubuntu. Awesome workaround guys. top notch